# Why capture node screenshot not capturing IFrame images correctly?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, html2canvas, image-capture, webpage-screenshot

I am trying to get the images with capture node screenshot option in chrome. It's working on all elements and images except iframe images. For example go to this link ( https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_height_width_css ) inspect the page and right click on this 

(

## This page is displayed in an iframe

)

 tag then select Capture node screenshot you will not get actual image.

I have also tried with element capture screenshot extensions  which are available in chrome store but non of them worked on iframe. Please any one tell how to capture of element or image in iframe properly with extensions or any JavaScript library like html2canvas?

Comment: your link doesnt work

Comment: Hi, I have updated the link, It's working now please check.

Comment: @Anonymous cross-origin policy maybe